# Create event handlers manually in ZipForge

Tags: delphi, event-handling, unzip

I used to drop [TZipForge](http://componentace.com/unzip-in-delphi.htm) component on a form so I could use its event handlers. Now, I'm using several thread worker to extract some zip files, therefore I create an instance of the TZipForge class as a local variable. How do I make the event handlers without Event tab in Object Inspector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a event hanlder manually yo must create a procedure with match with the declaration of the target event and then assign the *Address* of that procedure to the event of the class, for example if  you want to create a event handle for the [`OnFileProgress`](http://www.componentace.com/help/zf_guide/onfileprogress.htm) event you must create a procedure like this inside of your class.

```
procedure  FileProgress(Sender: TObject; FileName: string;
Progress: Double; Operation: TZFProcessOperation;
ProgressPhase: TZFProgressPhase; var Cancel: Boolean);
```

Check this sample

```
procedure TForm1.FileProgress(Sender: TObject; FileName: string;
  Progress: Double; Operation: TZFProcessOperation;
  ProgressPhase: TZFProgressPhase; var Cancel: Boolean);
begin
     //do your stuff here
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Archiver : TZipForge;
begin
  Archiver := TZipForge.Create(nil);
  try          
      Archiver.OnFileProgress:=FileProgress;//<- Here the event handler is assigned
      Archiver.FileName := 'compressedfile.zip';
      Archiver.OpenArchive(fmOpenRead);
      try
        Archiver.BaseDir := 'C\Foo';
        Archiver.ExtractFiles('*.*');
      finally
        Archiver.CloseArchive();
      end;
  finally
    Archiver.Free;
  end;
end;
```